# Reduce size of Tensorflow SavedModel for Google ML Engine deployment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

I have developed and trained a CNN Keras model and now I want to deploy this model to Google Machine Learning Engine, so I can execute predictions using their API.

I have converted to SavedModel format and the export/saved_model.pb has 14MB and the /export/variables/ directory has around 380MB. Google ML Engine has a limit of 250MB for this data and does not allow deploying a bigger model.

I saw a solution regarding https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms, but I still didn't manage to bezel build this project due to VS unmet dependencies.

Is there any other way to reduce/compress (especially) the variables directory? What I would want is to convert dtype from int64 to int32, but don't know the format of variables.data-00000-of-00001 file.

Thanks a lot!

I attach my Keras model to Tensorflow SavedModel code here:

```
# reset session
K.clear_session()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

# disable loading of learning nodes
K.set_learning_phase(0)

# load model
model = load_model('local-activity-recognition-model.h5')
config = model.get_config()
weights = model.get_weights()
new_Model = Model.from_config(config)
new_Model.set_weights(weights)

# export saved model
export_path = '.' + '/export'
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'export_input': new_Model.input},
                              outputs={'export_output': new_Model.output})

with K.get_session() as sess:
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                     tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                     signature_def_map={
                                                 signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature})
builder.save()
```

Comment: If you email us at cloudml-feedback@google.com we can probably increase your quota. That said, having a more compact model can sometimes also improve the latency.

Comment: I know that a smaller model is preferred, but I use it for research purposes at my university and would like to do a proof-of-concept only. Would a quota increase be possible if I am using a trial account? Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yes, we can grant the request to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can freeze the graph, that should shrink it down a bit.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph_test.py

If you're building a classifier, you might want to step to InceptionV3 architecture, this can easily be trained by tensorflows retrain code. This architecture is only 90mb.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining
https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible in your model to set the dtype of the Variables when building the graph? Using float32 while training is generally a good idea.

You can also use the techniques described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization), but they take a little more effort.